# jquery selects returning undefined value - asp.net webform

Tags: jquery, asp.net

simple bit of jquery. I have a div with clss linklist, inside it has several linkbuttons

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {

                $('#linklist a').each(function () {
                    alert(this.text);
                });
            });
</script>
```

I would assume that it should alert the text inside each rendered hyperlink. instead I am getting the value "undefined"

if i change it to

```
alert(this.id);
```

i am getting the correct client id - therefore i know at least that I am selecting correct.
why is this value undefined? same goes for this.text and this.value

Thanks

Comment: Please post the HTML too

Comment: working for me: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/kULgQ/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` inside the event handler is the native DOM element.

When you do `this.id` you are getting the `id` property of the DOMElement (an anchor). But it does **not** have a `text` property.

To get the text of the anchor, use:

```
// turn "this" to a jquery object and use .text()
$(this).text()
```

Or staying native javascript, you can:

```
this.textContent || this.innerText
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.linklist a').each(function () {
        alert(this.text);
    });
});
```